# Dynamic LINQ IQueryable (Generate Expression at runtime)

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have the following query

```
query.Join(
    relationEntity,
    entity => new { Prop1 = EF.Property<object>(entity, "Id"), Prop2 = Ef.Property...},
    relation => new { Prop1 = EF.Property<object>(relation, "EntityId"), Prop2 = EF.Property... },
    (Entity, Relation) => new { Entity, Relation })
```

I need to generate the keys at runtime. How can that be achieved? I already tried to build a Expression at runtime but it looks like the Join takes the recieved value literally so if I call a method there it gets translated to that method name instead of the result.

The method I'm testing with atm:

```
   private static object MyMethod(object entity, string name)
             => new { Id = EF.Property<object>(entity, name) };



   query.Join(
        relationEntity,
        entity => MyMethod(entity, "Id"),
        relation => MyMethod(relation, "EntityId"),
        (Entity, Relation) => new { Entity, Relation })
```

Comment: You should put the code you tried with Expressions in your Question.
If you put a Method.Call in your Expression, of course it's executed at expression runtime. If you want it to be computed at compile-time, you have to create a constant expression. Like new ConstantExpression(math.sqrt(2)). This will call the sqrt at compile time, or if you include a variable, at time of creation of the expression.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the info, I have two problems there that I don't know how to solve, the first one is dynamically building that new { Prop = EF.., Prop2 = EF... } based on a list of property names. And the second one is the one described by you. (I've edited the question to show the method that I have atm) I've tested so many different ways that I don't even remember them all :D

Comment: The word Expression is still not appearing in your Code.  What is not working ? (It's not working in LINQ to SQL for sure, is this the question ?) . Dynamicly building a Type at runtime is not possible with Expressions. But this is easy to workaround with using a known type.

Comment: Yes it is with LINQ to SQL. I'm using EFCore 3.1. But the properties are shadow properties that's why the need for the Ef.Property...

Comment: So what is the variable in here ? Why you are not just entity => entity.ID ?
Entity must have a known type, why you are using object so much ? An SQL Query cannot be generated, if you join on "object". SQL cannot compare objects. what are the types of query and relationEntity ?

Comment: I'm building a generic extension that have to run to all entities, the problem is that the entities can have composite keys and some of them are shadow properties. So I have at runtime to check the keys for the given entity and join with the other table based on those keys. I don't have navigation properties either. If I have a entity with only one column and PrimaryKey it's straightforward I can just call entity => Ef.Property<object>(entity, propertyName); But that won't work for entities with composite keys. I known I can create a composite key (in code using the anonymous type)

Comment: Like entity => new { Prop1 = EF.Property<object>(entity, prop1Name), Prop2 = EF.Property<object>(entity, prop2Name)}; The problem is that I don't know how many keys I'll have nor are they a fixed number of them. I've tested some code that generates the desired class. but then I didn't managed to make that entity => MyMethod work. since the expression goes as MyMethod instead of the result of it. And I'm clueless on how to make it call it like you said in your first comment.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is you don't know whether your primary keys are integers or strings. You can add the dynamic on the choice of columns, but not on the datatype.

Comment: EntityFrameworks deal with the types by itself, that isn't a problem. I just have to give it EF.Property<object> and it works (that I've tested already). Do you have some minutes to chat?

Comment: The code where you decide how many components are in your key, is missing. Maybe you can return Tuple<T>, Tuple<T, T1>, Tuple<T, T1, T2> depending on how many parts you have. If you have really endless numbers of keys, you would have to build your own type with typebuilder. This is quiet an effort at the end.

Comment: I didn't remember to try with Tuples, they have enough fields for me. But I still don't understand how to make this  entity => Tuple.Create(EF.Property<object>(entity, "Id")), execute the actual Tuple.Create instead of passing it as the expression. Can you show me how to do that plz? It's generating this: inner: c => Tuple.Create<object>(EF.Property<object>(c, \"Id\")) instead of using the actual value. I know how to take the actual tuple creation out of there but the problem that I initially had remains, it does not execute the method it's just being used as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Make your MyMethod an expression you have to approach it like this

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> MyMethod<T>(string name) => 
         (T entity) => new { Id = EF.Property<object>(entity, name) };

query.Join(
    relationEntity,
    MyMethod<entityType>("Id"),
    MyMethod<relationType>("EntityId"),
    (Entity, Relation) => new { Entity, Relation })
```

The Method has to return an Expression, not any computed result.

But as more complex your MyMethod will be, as less likely you will be able to convert it to SQL.

This here is more about keeping your code shorter and more readable. There is nothing dynamic in there yet.

Something like this is not a problem, since this selection is executed before SQL-Creation.

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> MyMethod<T>(string name) 
{ 
    if (case 1)
         return (T entity) => new { Id = EF.Property<object>(entity, name) };
    if (case 2) 
         return (T entity) => new { Id = EF.Property<object>(entity, name), Id2 = ... something else }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very mutch, just to make sure. That second part there is no way to actually make it dynamic right?

Comment: The second part is for the variable number of arguments, actually it should work without Tuples. But right now the function has only one name argument, for one ID, no idea how you will deal with more composite key parts. It's more a strategy, than a solution. And you have to ensure somehow, that the 2 calls to MyMethod will return the same type of object, not one with 2 keys one with 5 keys, or so.